# Node-red post returns partial XML response

Tags: xml, http, node-red

When I post an XML payload to a server using Postman, I get a full response.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userResponse>
    <status>1</status>
    <message></message>
    <results>
        <account>
            <email>foo@example.com</email>
            <username>developer</username>
            <status>1</status>
        </account>
        <contact>
            <firstName>foo</firstName>
            <lastName>bar</lastName>
        </contact>
    </results>
</userResponse>
```

But when I submit the same payload through the node-red http request, I get a partial response.

```javascript
msg.payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><userRequest><authentication><username>foo</username><password>bar</password></authentication><action>get</action></userRequest>';
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['content-type'] = 'application/xml';
return msg;

// Response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userResponse>
    <status>1</status>
    <message></message>
</userResponse>
```

The flow is very simple.  http in, function to define headers and payload as above, http post, http response.

There is no processing of the response at all in this flow.

Why might node-red be dropping the 'results' from the response?

My guesses so far are:

1. Node-red is not able to parse it properly, so it drops unparsable data.  But I ran the full response through an XML validator and found no problems
2. The request isn't waiting long enough for the full response and truncating

Two things I notice in the Postman response:

- Content-Encoding → gzip
- Content-Type → text/html; charset=UTF-8

Those beg the questions:

- Can node-red decode gzip by default?
- Will it respond properly to an XML response that claims to be text/html?
- If not, how to deal with it other than asking the client to fix their response?

I'm not sure where to look from here. What testing can I do to narrow it down?

**Update: Seems to not be headers or timeout causing the issue**

I setup another flow to mock the response. Calling it in the same way gets the whole XML body correctly. Adding a 2 second delay also gets the full body correctly with all of the same XML data that my client's API is returning when I call it from Postman.

The client changed the response header for content type to text/xml. This changed nothing in what node-red returns as a response. It's still missing inside data.

So, it's not the data because if I request it with Postman and copy-paste that into the msg of a new flow that returns it when requested, node-red shows all of the data.

It also doesn't seem to matter what headers are sent.

I haven't eliminated gzip as a cause, but it seems that it's not actually encoded since node-red is returning some of the msg.

I need some ideas for how to trace the request and response and find where it's different from doing the mock response.

How can I debug the msg flow inside the node-red post request?

Comment: The msg you are updating to send out in the POST will have some system-inserted values from the incoming http request that triggered the flow, perhaps these are affecting the outgoing POST or perhaps the msg being sent to the ending http response node has been affected by the intermediate http request node. Add debugs either side of the http request  to see the complete msg, do a detailed comparison between what you get with your mock flow (which presumably uses an inject, i.e. msg doesn't have the fields that are in a msg from an incoming http input node) and what you get with the real flow.

Comment: If the mock flow is showing all the data correctly back from the POST then the problem isn't inherent to nodered/bluemix, it's something to do with the specifics of the msg being used in the http request node in your real flow